# 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full

Tags: sql-server, query, disk-space, filegroups, data

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

An OLE DB record is available.

Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.X' in database 'MyDatabase' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. 
Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, 
adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.".

Why i getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn’t necessarily mean your disk is full. It means the file(s) which store your data have reached their maximum allocated size.

Check your data file setup (right-click on database - properties - files) then check the initial size, autogrowth enabled, and if the file(s) is limited to a set size.

If autogrowth is not enabled and you have disk space on the volume where it is stored, you can enable it and it will expand when needed. The other way is to truncate/purge some tables, this will free space.

Comment: Thanks for information